# RcppArmadillo and Header Files

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo

I wrote an R package that makes use of RcppArmadillo. There are various C++ functions that multiple of the `.cpp` files call. Instead of adding the functions to each of the `.cpp` files, I want to make use of header files. And it these header files regarding which I would like to clarify a few questions.

Assume that I have two header files, `header1.h` and `header2.h`, with the functions A to C and D to F respectively.

`header1.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

arma::mat A(arma::vec &X, double Y);
arma::vec B(arma::mat &X, unsigned int Y);
amra::sp_mat C(arma::mat &X, int Y);

#endif
```

`header2.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

double D(arma::vec &X, double Y);
int E(arma::mat &X, unsigned int Y);
unsigned int F(arma::mat &X, int Y);

#endif
```

Files `header1.cpp` and `header2.cpp` define the mentioned functions. Files `example1.cpp` and `example2.cpp` contain functions that call functions A to F and include the respective headers via

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
```

1. `example1.cpp` and `example2.cpp` begin with

   ```
   #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
   // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
   // [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
   #include <omp.h>
   // [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

   using namespace Rcpp;
   ```

Is it sufficient to simply move this block of code to `header1.h` and `header2.h`, omitting it from `header1.cpp`, `header2.cpp`, `example1.cpp`, and `example2.cpp`?

2. Which is the correct directory of `header1.h`, `header2.h`, `header1.cpp`, and `header2.cpp`? Are they to be placed in `/inst/include` with a `packagename.h` file that refers to the individual header files? Or should I put them into the `/src` directory? I found indications of both options.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the 900+ CRAN packages using RcppArmadillo and see if you find one that does things the way you want them to be?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I checked a few and I did not get a clear answer. Some package appear to have header files in both `/inst/include` and in `/src`. And they are not aligned in where they place lines from the example block of code in question 1. Thus, I posted these questions here on SO.

Comment: So the answer then is that both approaches work. Just pick one.

Comment: What about question 1? Is it sufficient to place these lines of code in the header files?

Comment: And regarding question 2: which one is the recommended choice?

Comment: You may have better luck on the rcpp-devel list with open ended question;  I am a bit short on time and nobody else seems to bite here at SO.  The list is pretty friendly, and a few knowledgeable users may be able to help you if (sign up first and then) post there.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks, I will look into that.